# I'm building a CNN in python but when training it it's sstop trainging and give me a WARNING

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I use keras with tensorflow backend i fininshed a CNN that can classify between dog and cat but when i fit it it's stop and give me this :

```
**Found 8000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 2000 images belonging to 2 classes.
Epoch 1/25
 250/8000 [..............................] - ETA: 17:40 - loss: 0.6781 - accuracy: 0.6084WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 200000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 2000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
 250/8000 [..............................] - 39s 157ms/step - loss: 0.6781 - accuracy: 0.6084 - val_loss: 0.6047 - val_accuracy: 0.6650**
```

this is the code of fitting :

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
 ``train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(64, 64),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='binary') #validation_generator
classifier.fit(
        training_set,
        steps_per_epoch=8000,#traing image
        epochs=25,
        validation_data=test_set,
        validation_steps=2000)#validation_steps number of testing image
#we use training set and test set acc to check if there is a overfittin
```

g

Comment: Well, according to the output of the Warning, wherever you are getting data from does not provide the correct amount of data. You'll need to resolve that so that the CNN receives the proper amount of data it is expecting to complete it's training.

Comment: I cheacked the amount of data its correct

Comment: Correct by your standards, or correct by the CNN standards? Per the Warning, the CNN needs enough data for 2000 batches. Does that match the size of the data you are passing in?

Answer (score 0):

Each epoch should span your whole training dataset. It is basically how many times you want to use your whole dataset to train your model.

Because of memory constraints you need to train in batches instead of loading everything at once.

So number of batches * batch size = total training examples

Set steps_per_epoch to num_training_examples/batch_size. Take the ceiling of that value.

So for your case, 8000/32 = 250.

Comment: I do that but when it reach 250 it  stop, I'm new in deep learning it is my first week i dont understand why  we reduce steps_per_epoch

Comment: Oh my bad, your batch size is 32. Edited my answer.